# Themes Stylesheet.css class is overlapping the current page Stylesheet class

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

in my asp.net application i've used 2 Stylesheets :

1. in App_Theme/JobTheme/Stylesheet.css
2. css/StylesheetNew.css (for a page which i am opening as a **popup in an iframe**)

in **App_Theme/JobTheme/Stylesheet.css** :

```
body{height: 100%;width: 100%;background: #fff;font: 12px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif; }
```

and in  **css/StylesheetNew.css** :

```
body{ background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica,Tahoma;font-size:75%; margin:5px;}
```

but when i am opening the popup its **taking the body styles of App_Theme/JobTheme/Stylesheet.css** *instead of* **css/StylesheetNew.css**

```
Why App_Theme/JobTheme/Stylesheet.css is overlapping the css/StylesheetNew.css?
and how to avoid this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check on hierarchy of stylesheets loaded. your page specific stylesheet should load after theme stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways, one is to ensure that you only use one CSS stylesheet for each div or `body{}` in this case.

The second way is to ensure that the stylesheet you are using is referenced **after** the first stylesheet, this has always worked for me in the past as CSS reads from the top down

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked the css/StylesheetNew.css to the popup page.